# Why isn't there a cloud services related topic on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As a developer I often find myself substituting/moving pieces of codes by services (managed) already provided by cloud providers.

Questions raise on how to use those services, programming against those services, but Stack Overflow is not the best fit, and I might find my question to be off-topic and marked as eligible to be closed.

Is there a Stack Exchange site that is already intended for this (may be not so explicitly)?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136823/where-do-cloud-solution-api-questions-go

Comment: Asking how to program against those services should be on topic on SO. Asking how to choose one, of course, is not. Asking how to “use” them is fuzzy; some such questions are best for the service provider: it’s their product. But the more you focus on the technical details and less on features and benefits, the more topical your question will be. The more you focus on features and benefits, the further you wander into subjective territory, the extremum being shopping questions. As to “why” SE doesn’t host subjective questions: we tried, and the system is bad at handling them.

Comment: @DanBron I do agree with you.And I post this coz I was suggested by the SO community and warned to be out of scope there. Since question was very borderline or maybe OT.... subjective as you said... Never find yourself programming against those and then find out it’s a matter of better knowing the service and saving you from coding something that’s partially already served? Better cloud sw engineering topic? other point is how big and if the service provider is...they do invent new standards and saying: questions related the service is for them...I do not completely agree it’s general topic